# Opening a mysql db without a server running

Tags: linux, mysql, database

I am tasked with debugging a program in a language I am not familiar with that runs. Since the bug only appears on live, I have to be extremely careful. That much for background.

That server I am connected to is a Debian system. I have root access and connect via ssh.

On the server are MySQL DB files. Multiple files. What's not on it is a MySQL-server. `netstat -tulpn`, `systemctl`, and `dpkg -l` confirm it.

Here's my problem. The previous dev could connect to the server and take a look at the databases. Or at least I was told that by my boss. I now operate under the assumption that this is somehow possible with the tools installed.

For the last few hours, I went through the code of the application, thinking he might just use the code's database adapter and might have left a script somewhere in there. But it doesn't look like that. So I am asking if anyone knows a way to open a MySQL DB like an SQLite DB? Maybe it is something fairly standard already integrated into MySQL-client or so. I can't imagine that a whole SQL server is integrated into the client, but I have been wrong in the past.

Comment: Hi there, It would be better If you could show us output for the commands you listed , any installed tools that you suppose should work with, any code portion that shows database connectivity or any other useful information. This would help you get better answers.

Comment: I understand. But at the same moment, I try to walk a very narrow line about what I am allowed to post and what not. It is already helpful knowing that no one instantly jumped to the question with a simple solution. It tells me a haven't overlooked something incredibly basic. Posting code segments here is out of the question. For the outputs of those commands, well `netstat -tulpn` had no port 3306 open. `systemctl status mysql` didn't know the service `dpkg -l` didn't have mysql-server.

Comment: You could have mariadb installed, listening only on a unix socket.

Comment: MariaDb isn't installed either

Comment: The DB server could be running in a docker container. `docker images` will tell you if Docker is installed on that system and list existing images, and if so `docker ps` tells you what containers are currently running, `docker ps -a` tell you also about containers that are no longer running. If so it is just a matter of finding how the mysqldb container is started (look for scripts with `docker run`....). Depending on installation, you may need to do sudo to use the `docker` command.

Comment: Docker is a good idea, but we do use it daily, so I checked for that. The solution was incredibly simple in the end, I was told the wrong server. That's why nothing made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, for your help. As it turned out, I was told the completely wrong server and that was why nothing made sense. As soon as I was redirected to the right server, everything was standard.